# counting strings through columns

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm pretty new to python or programming at all so I'd like to get help on the following problem
My table is set up like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZQAi.png

Now I try to count all '✓' and set the number to column Teilnahme.

```
teilnahmencounter(ctx):
i=0
#  Connect
connection = sqlite3.connect("kekse.db")
#  cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

#  Abfrage
sql = "SELECT * FROM kekse ORDER BY ID"
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
for dsatz in cursor:
    i = 0
    for x in range(2 , 19):
        if str(dsatz[x]) == '✓':
            i += 1
    cursor.execute('UPDATE kekse SET Teilnahme='+str(i)+' WHERE ID=?', dsatz[0]
                   )
    connection.commit()
    #print(dsatz[1], i, "Teilnahmen")

connection.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So does this not work?

Comment: It doesn't, it's not leaving the second for query

Comment: Not sure what that means - do you compute i correctly?  The inner for loop over the row seems ok (though I would do it a different way) - so if you can explain exactly what was wrong

Comment: Ran it several times, but it never gets back into my first for part or the print(dsatz[1],i,Teilnahmen)

Comment: Try doing `for row in  cursor.execute(query)` because the execute query returns a iterator which may not be in the cursor.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure that I got what you try to tell me. which can be missing if I select * ?

Comment: I had a look at these documents - but generally when you are doing a select query execution you get a iterator object. So put the select statement where I said “query”. I would say before doing any update statements just create the sql query to ensure your logic is even correct :)

Comment: Getting 'ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type'

Answer (score 0):

Try and use cast in your update where its getting updated -

```
import sqlite3
#  Connect
con = sqlite3.connect("dbname.db")
#  cursor
cur = con.cursor()
for row in cur.execute("select * from testtab"):
    print(row)
 
cur.execute("update testtab set id=21 where id = cast("+str(2)+" as int)")
con.commit()
con.close()
```